# Can Google's patented ML algorithms be used commercially?

Tags: neural-networks, q-learning, dropout, google, legal

I just find that Google patents some of the widely used machine learning algorithms. For example:

- [System and method for addressing overfitting in a neural network](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9406017B2/en) (Dropout?)
- [Processing images using deep neural networks](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9715642B2/en)
- [Methods and apparatus for reinforcement learning](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150100530) (Q-Learning?)

Does that mean I can't use those algorithms commercially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can you use them commercially?**

Yes.

**Is Google able to sue you any time they want?**

Yes.

**Will they do that...**

Probably not.

Google isn't a known patent bully, I would give them the benefit of the doubt in this kind of situation and say, unless you start really giving them real trouble, they wouldn't do anything. Some companies/people know an idea can really be used for good and patent it to protect its use not to inhibit its use. By patenting the idea and setting a precedent of not suing they are effectively allowing everyone to benefit. Maybe in the future Google cloud, Azure and Amazon web services will lose some money in a legal battle, but I doubt you personally will be hit with a lawsuit.

Comment: As a small note: in the unlikely case that you do develop software based on this patent that _directly competes_ with Google, and even in such a way that it threatens their revenue, they will find any and all possible ways to shut you down - including patent infringement (as is their right). I agree that you should just use it, but keep it in the back of your head that they still _can_ sue if they want.